# Кнопка в кнопке или двойная кнопка

Tags: java, android

Вот стоковый будильник. Как видно на скриншоте, есть кнопка шириной MATCH_PARENT, 
а вот справа есть еще одна кнопка будильника, состояние вкл\выкл. 
Как сделать так-же, кнопку в кнопке при **динамическом** добавлении из кода?

Так я добавляю кнопку, как добавить 2 кнопки на 1 область экрана?

```
private void addViewButton(String dateFromTimePicker) {
    //установили размеры кнопки
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParam
            = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, SIZE_HEIGHT_BUTTON);

    //добавили новую кнопку
    Button newClock = new Button(this);
    newClock.setText(dateFromTimePicker);
    newClock.setTextSize(SIZE_TEXT);
    selectClockView.addView(newClock, btnParam);
}
```

[image: Кнопка 1]

Comment: Я не понел вы хотите одну кнопку внутри другой ??\

Comment: Вы можете обрабатывать клик на любом `View`, в том числе и родительском контейнере (как в случае приложения "Будильник" на вашем скриншоте), просто "повесив" слушаетель кликов (`ClickListener`) на этот виджет, не обязательно именно на кнопке. Для некоторых виджетов, как `ImageView` требуется включить регистрацию кликов через `setClickable(true)`

Comment: А не проще `ToggleButton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтоб "Навесить" view на view используйте `RelativeLayout` в место `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#f43324"
        android:id="@+id/btnFIRST"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

А чтоб кнопка отображалась или нет воспользуйтесь функцией

```
btnFIRST.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//видима
btnFIRST.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//не видима
```

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно. Однако я добавляю динамически кнопку(из кода, во время работы приложения, см код) 
Сделал так:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnParamOnOff
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btnParamOnOff.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, newClock.getId());`

Но все в верхнем левом углу..

Comment: @Roman Aymaletdinov, а Вам таки обязательно создавать её программно? Можно описать в разметке изначально скрытой, а потом динамически делать видимой/невидимой. А программно Вам нужно правило `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT`

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы решили мой вопрос!

Answer (score -1):

добавьте обе кнопки в один контейнер(LinearLayout).При нажатии на кнопку вкл прячьте кнопку вкл( setVisibility(btn_On.GONE)) а кнопку выкл показывайте ( setVisibility(btn_Off.VISIBLE)).Точно так же наоборот..